# IP address and Network Interface

Tags: ip

Can some one please explain what this statement means - Strictly speaking, the IP address identifies the host's network interface rather than the host itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A host (e.g. your computer) can have more than one network interface (e.g. an ethernet card *and* a WiFi card).  In general, each interface will have a separate IP address.